# Proving a result on Lipschitz functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

To prove some convergence results for random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (Theorem 2.7, Asymptotic Statistics), Van der Vaart uses the following claim:

"For every $f$ with a range $[0, 1]$ and Lipschitz norm at most $1$ and every $\epsilon >0$,
$$|Ef(X_n) - Ef(Y_n)|\le \epsilon E1_{\{d(X_n, Y_n)\le\epsilon \}} + 2E1_{\{d(X_n, Y_n)>\epsilon \}}."$$
Where $d(x, y)$ is a distance function on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I could not figure out a proof for this claim, nor find any reference for it. Is there any quick way of showing this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expectation is linear, so one has 
$$|Ef(X_n) - Ef(Y_n)| = |E(f(X_n) - f(Y_n))|$$ 
$$= \bigg|\int_X (f(X_n) - f(Y_n))\bigg|$$
Here $(X,\mu)$ denotes the probability space. Now break the domain of integration 
into $d(X_n,Y_n) \leq \epsilon$ and $d(X_n,Y_n) > \epsilon$ parts. The integral 
can then be written as 
$$\int_{\{x \in X:\,d(X_n,Y_n)\leq \epsilon\}} (f(X_n) - f(Y_n))\,d\mu + 
\int_{\{x \in X:\,d(X_n,Y_n)> \epsilon\}} (f(X_n) - f(Y_n))\,d\mu$$
Use the Lipschitz condition on the first integral, and the fact that $|f| \leq 1$ on the second integral, to get the bound you want.

Comment: perfect! Just one observation: if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not defined on necessarily the same probability space, say $X_n$ on $(\Omega_X, \mathcal{F}_X, \mathbb{P}_X)$ and $Y_n$ on $(\Omega_Y, \mathcal{F}_Y, \mathbb{P}_Y)$, could we still use the linearity of expectation argument? To put things in context, for weak (distribution) mode of convergence, random sequences need not be defined on the same underlying measurable space.

Comment: You could view $X_n$ and $Y_n$ as defined on $(\Omega_X \times \Omega_Y, {\mathcal F}_X \times {\mathcal F}_Y, {\mathbb P}_X \times {\mathbb P}_Y)$ if you have a known joint distribution, such as when they are independent. Then your equation will make sense and the above again applies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$, we have that

$$\mathbb{E}[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]=\mathbb{E}[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|1_{d(X_n,Y_n)>\epsilon}]+\mathbb{E}[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|1_{d(X_n,Y_n)\leq\epsilon}]$$

Then we can use that $f\leq1$, along with the triangle inequality, to bound the first term and the Lipschitz condition (i.e. $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x,y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^k$) to bound the second term on the right hand side.